# images and video collage like facebook

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a images and videos collage like facebook post. if there are more than 5 items then there should be +2 like facebook

I have created recycler view with staggered layout but recycler view is scrollable and I am unable to achieve output

Comment: You need to share what you've tried so far in code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.